# Conditionally adding day to previous date in column

Tags: date, excel, addition, vba

I have the data in an excel column:
 (Before)

```
4/22/16
4/22/16
4/22/16
4/22/16
11/13/20
11/13/20
5/14/16
5/14/16
5/14/16
5/14/16
5/14/16
5/14/16
5/14/16
```

This is just a sample of hundreds lines of data. How would I create a macro that lets me add a day to the previous day before it (but stops when the following day isn't the same and then continues to the next line) So, I would want
 (After)

```
4/22/16
4/23/16
4/24/16
4/25/16
11/13/20
11/14/20
5/14/16
5/15/16, and etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

With dates in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,A2)
```

and copy down:

[image]